# Microsoft Access SQL nested select statments

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I give temporary name to tables formed from select statments in access sql?
I have this:

```
SELECT PUNONJES.[ID_P], PUNONJES.[Emer]
FROM PUNONJES, PUSHIM
WHERE PUNONJES.[ID_P] = PUSHIM.[#ID_P] 
  AND PUSHIM.[Kohezgjatja] > (SELECT AVG(PUSHIM.[Kohezgjatja]) FROM PUSHIM)
```

I want to store the above selection in a temp table lets say temp then use another selection below on the temp table and so on. How to do that?

Comment: In Access if you save a query as say Temp then you can use Temp in other queries in the same way you use tables

Answer (score 0):

A general outline for single-user situation might be --

```
' determine if temp table exists
If DCount("*", "MSYSOBJECTS", "Type = 1 and Name = 'temp'") = 0 Then
    ' temp table does not exist, create it with columns [ID_P] and [Emer]
    ....
EndIf


' empty the table of any prior records
...
"DELETE * From temp;"



' now use your prior sql, wrapped with Insert
INSERT INTO temp
SELECT PUNONJES.[ID_P], PUNONJES.[Emer]
FROM PUNONJES, PUSHIM
WHERE PUNONJES.[ID_P] = PUSHIM.[#ID_P] 
  AND PUSHIM.[Kohezgjatja] > (SELECT AVG(PUSHIM.[Kohezgjatja]) FROM PUSHIM)
```

For a multi-user situation you need to preface the rows with a UserID or some uniquifier and change the Delete and the Insert to use it.